# Make javascript validation happen sooner on click?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

So I have a form as such:

```
 <form action="URL" name=myform method=post onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this)" autocomplete=off>
```

When the form is submitted, it checks for validation.

Earlier though, I have code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
    $("#submitbutton").click(function() {

      var fname = $("input#first_name").val();
      var lname = $("input#last_name").val();
      var email = $("input#email").val();
      var leadsource = $("input#leadsource").val();
      var country = $("input#country").val();
      var phone = $("input#phone").val();
      var oid = $("input#oid").val();
      var retURL = $("input#retURL").val();
      var crazy
= $("input#00N40000001mCkP").val();
        var dataString = '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone + '&oid=' + oid + '&retURL=' + retURL + '&leadsource=' + leadsource + '&country=' + country;   //alert (dataString);return false;   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MYURL.php?first_name="
+ fname + "&last_name=" + lname,
    data: dataString, 
    success: function(response) { $(myform).submit(); }
    });
    return false;   });

  });   </script>
```

Essentially whats happening is, the form data is initially sent to a different url through an AJAX submit prior to completing the real form. On success of the ajax push - the form is submitted, and then the form is validated.

I need the form validation to have right when #submitbutton is clicked though - prior to the ajax request. Any ideas?

Comment: It'd really help people trying to help you if you'd format your code so that it wasn't so jumbled and confusing.

Answer (score 1):

That code should work just fine. If you want to add it to a `onclick=` property on the element (I wouldn't, but if you insist), you can use this syntax to reference the form:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return validateFormOnSubmit(this.parentNode)" />
```

And you'd have to do an `e.preventDefault()` and `return false` (maybe just one?) from the `validateFormOnSubmit()` function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how I would implement this?

Comment: The last two lines prevent the button from being "clicked" (no trigger). You call those only when you don't want the form to submit. Otherwise, just let it run normally.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) . Also, you can call validateFormOnSubmit in the anon function above and return false if it validation doesn't pass.

Answer (score 0):

you should put some " " around your form tags attributes, and give it an id!

just call your validate function as the first line in your button click handler :)

```
 $("#submitbutton").click(function(e) {
   if( validateFormOnSubmit($('#myform'))){
       //do all the posting stuff

   }
   else{
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
```